# jquery increase by 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

Afternoon,

I would like to increase the number in this code by 1 for each question displayed.

```
 new_question = "<div id=\"" + res.qId + "\">" +
                            "<h1>Question 1</h1>" +
                            "<p><i>" + res.question + "</i></p>" +
                            "<div class=\"answer-grid\">" +
                            "<div id=\"a1\" class=\"answer\">" +
                            "<p>" + res.answer1 + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + res.answer2 + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + res.answer3 + "</p>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "</div>";
```

With this it would show, question 1, question 2, and so on...

How would i go about doing this in jQuery please?

***Update*** Victor provided what i needed, thanks all for your help. Updated code below.

```
 var questionNumber = 1;
    $.each(result, function (index, res) {
        new_question = "<div id=\"" + res.qId + "\">" +
                        "<h1>Question " + (questionNumber++) + "</h1>" +
                        "<p><i>" + res.question + "</i></p>" +
                        "<div class=\"answer-grid\">" +
                        "<div id=\"a1\" class=\"answer\">" +
                        "<p>" + res.answer1 + "</p>" +
                        "<p>" + res.answer2 + "</p>" +
                        "<p>" + res.answer3 + "</p>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "</div>";

        $('#pinfos').append(new_question);
```

Comment: which one of the numbers would you like to increase? the h1 text?

Comment: no just where it says Question 1. Im showing 6 questions, and would like to have question 2, question 3, etc :)

Comment: No need for jQuery here.

Comment: So are talking about the text in the <h1> tag!

Comment: all done, Victor gave what i was after. Thanks all for you help.

Comment: Where is your "res" object getting it's values from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable outside your loop and incremenet it inside your loop and use that in the markup.

```
var questionNumber=0;

$.each(someJsonData, function (index, res) {
{
 questionNumber++;
 new_question = "<div id=\"" + res.qId + "\">" +
                            "<h1>Question "+questionNumber+"</h1>" +
                            "<p><i>" + res.question + "</i></p>" +
                            "<div class=\"answer-grid\">" +
                            "<div id=\"a1\" class=\"answer\">" +
                            "<p>" + res.answer1 + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + res.answer2 + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + res.answer3 + "</p>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "</div>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a var called questionNumber and increment it at each call

```
var questionNumber = 1;
        $.each(result, function (index, res) {
            new_question = "<div id=\"" + res.qId + "\">" +
                            "<h1>Question " + (questionNumber++) + "</h1>" +
                            "<p><i>" + res.question + "</i></p>" +
                            "<div class=\"answer-grid\">" +
                            "<div id=\"a1\" class=\"answer\">" +
                            "<p>" + res.answer1 + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + res.answer2 + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + res.answer3 + "</p>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "</div>";

            $('#pinfos').append(new_question);
```

Comment: Awesome, worked a treat. Updated you code to show where i needed it Many thanks @Victor-Eloy